# How can i transfer data from one table to another database table using laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying hard to get transfer data of one database table to another database table

Via Laravel migration, I have raw database queries like below

```
insert into users 
    ( temp_foreign_id, aadhar_card, created_at, date_of_birth, deleted, email, email_verified, name, pan_number, passport_no, password, phone, phone_verified, profile_photo_url, type, updated_at )
    ( select partners.id, null, partners.created, null, partners.deleted, partners.email, partners.email_verified, partners.name, null, null, partners.password, partners.phone, partners.phone_verified, JSON_EXTRACT ( partners.meta, '$.image' ), 'partner', partners.updated from hookfish.partners )");
```

I was trying to put it in migration file and run it like below

```
   <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    
    class UsersForPartners extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            
        DB::statement(DB::raw('SET @prev=0,@rownum=0;'));
        $result=DB::raw("insert into users 
        ( temp_foreign_id, aadhar_card, created_at, date_of_birth, deleted, email,
```

email_verified, name, pan_number, passport_no, password, phone, phone_verified, profile_photo_url, type, updated_at )
( select partners.id, null, partners.created, null, partners.deleted, partners.email, partners.email_verified, partners.name, null, null, partners.password, partners.phone, partners.phone_verified, JSON_EXTRACT ( partners.meta, '$.image' ), 'partner', partners.updated from hookfish.partners )");
}

Thanks for any help i can get from you all

Comment: Migration run Different database

Answer (score 0):

hey guys I got an answer to my question as I was going in the wrong way to run database raw queries in migration. I was trying DB::raw("") it was supposed to be DB::insert("query inside this") for inserting data from one schema to another and DB::select("raw query here") to select values from the table though I used DB::insert("") I got my data inserted from one table to another database table.

```
$result=DB::insert("insert into users 
        ( temp_foreign_id, aadhar_card, created_at, date_of_birth, deleted, email, email_verified, name, pan_number, passport_no, password, phone, phone_verified, profile_photo_url, type, updated_at )
        ( select raw_partners.id, raw_partners.aadhar_number, raw_partners.created, null, raw_partners.deleted, raw_partners.email, 0, raw_partners.name, raw_partners.pan_number, null, null, raw_partners.phone, 0, null, 'rera_partner', raw_partners.updated from hookfish.raw_partners )
        ");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).